# Why doesn't the default text direction for a TextView match the locale?

Tags: android, textview, locale, right-to-left

**TL;DR** In RTL layouts, should Latin text be mirrored, and if so why doesn't Android do this by default?

---

I am trying to implement RTL support in my app, and an issue I have run into is that Latin characters by default don't appear on the right side of a `TextView` or `EditText`. I would have thought that even if the app was not translated into an RTL language that the behaviour should be to still mirror the text.

Looking into it there is an easy fix by setting `android:textDirection="locale"` or even `android:textAlignment="viewStart"` but why isn't this the default to start with? So it makes me wonder whether this is the correct way to approach displaying RTL Latin text or whether it should still match the original script.

This is an image to help illustrate what I am referring to. Here the `EditText` cursor is over to the right but the English hint still remains over to the left.

[image: RTL issue]

Comment: Similar to TextView, the language of the hint has higher priority over the direction than the system layout direction. Try using an arabic hint.

Comment: Yes I realize an Arabic hint would work, but surely someone who uses an Arabic language would still expect Latin text to be over to the right? Especially as that's where the cursor is!

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. If what you say is to be followed then wouldn't it mean that the arabic text should start from left for us(who use ltr) and then it'd lose its meaning all together, I think? But it'd be great to confirm this from someone who uses arabic and get his ideas on this.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I'm not sure. However most Arabic apps I've seen put Latin text on the right because not everything is translated, like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/sjXCJ9zrVEp89meU8

Comment: Ohh, I think it's because they only design their app for RTL use-case. So their gravity and everything is right/end.

Comment: So surely someone who uses a RTL language would expect that then? Anyway, we need a native speaker to confirm this really!

Comment: Yeah, I can't say that for sure. If you've to go other way around then you can check for the device locale using `TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale` and then depending on that you can set gravity of your views to the right. Although, I'm not really sure how that'd work but worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm an Iranian and our language is RTL. Actually it totally depends on the design of your application but we usually expect the default behavior in most cases (like the photo you've provided). You can check the screenshots from Alibaba Travels which is the most popular application for buying plane tickets in Iran. When the name of the airports/cities are Farsi, they are aligned to right and vice versa for the English ones.

[image: Farsi names]
[image: English names]

But in some contexts like a table showing descriptions of a product that most items are RTL, it would totally make sense to align LTR items to the right. You can take a look at Digikala below (it's the biggest online store in Iran)

[image: Digikala]

Comment: Fascinating insight, thank you! So I guess the Android defaultdoes match your expectations. I noticed that the place icons in your second picture are left aligned, do they actually change dynamically along with the text (RTL or LTR)?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes the default behavior satisfies users in most cases. Also, DrawableStart would automatically align itself as far as I can remember.